# In created programmatically dxf dashed lines with custom type displays like solid

Tags: .net, autocad, dxf

I have some trouble with opening created programmatically (netdxf library) dxf document.
When I open single document from AutoCAD this document opens correctly. But if some document was opened from AutoCAD and I try to open my documen dashed lines displays like solid. But if I input REGEN from AutoCAD command line it displays correctly.
This dashed lines has a custom style. I set it from C# when I create document. And custom style with long distance from dashes displays correctly everytime. Only dashed lines with small dashes distance displays like solid.
How can I shoot this trouble? Set PsLtScale property to 0 or 1 I tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly standard behavior for AutoCAD.  AutoCAD will always try to minimize the amount of graphics processing that it does.  This means that it will try to **not** draw the spaces in a finely dashed line unless the user demands it (REGEN command), or unless you are zoomed in on the line.

AutoCAD will do the same thing with circles and arcs.  Especially in older versions, if you zoomed in and out a lot, your circles would be rendered as polygons, like octagons or even hexagons.  Using the REGEN command would then re-render them as 'circles' at your current zoom level.  (They are still drawn as polygons, but with enough sides that they look like circles).

Example in AutoCAD 2010:

Circles and HIDDEN line type after zooming in and out a lot:

[image]

After REGEN command:

[image]

Comment: Can I just add to this answer that 3D polylines don't display with dashed styles usually. In my experience I have had to flatten drawings for the line styles to take effect, in addition to the various LTSCALE and PSLTSCALE settings etc.  There is also PLINEGEN.